# Vite dynamic import of node_modules

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, vite

I'm having issues importing a library of svg assets in Vue 3 + Vite. This is the only option that I can use since we are exporting the library. Previously this works in Webpack, but not it seems to be broken when working with Vite.

This is the error I'm getting: Failed to resolve module specifier '@my-icons/lib/BrandA/check-icon.svg'

```
<template>
    <component
      :is="dynamicComponent"
      :class="$style.svg"
      :aria-label="title"
      :width="width"
      :height="height"
      @click="$emit('click')">
    </component>
  </template>
  
  <script>
  import { defineAsyncComponent  } from 'vue';
  
  export default {
    props: {
      icon: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      title: {
        type: String,
        default: null,
      },
      width: {
        type: [Number, String],
        default: 24,
      },
      height: {
        type: [Number, String],
        default: 24,
      },
    },
    computed: {
      dynamicComponent() {
        const iconBrand = this.$settings?.brand;
        const iconItem = async() => await import(`@my-icons/lib/${iconBrand}/${this.icon}.svg`);}
        return defineAsyncComponent(() => iconItem);
      }
    }
  };
  </script>
```

I tried to use import.meta.glob, extracting the contents of the library but none of it works.

Comment: If had console.log(iconItem) ? its not a js moudle ,so I think you  need a svg loader  to transform the svg file to a js module,